# ElasticSearch is not returning the document in correct order

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-5, elasticsearch-aggregation, elasticsearch-8

For the below query, I am searching the text "christ". the result is not showing the correct order. I have a record for "Christine" but it is not showing as a first document. Can you help me to fix this order issue? I am using Elasticsearch 8.5.3. but the same is correctly working in Elasticsearch 2.x version.

Mapping and Settings are below,

```
{
  "template": {
    "settings": {
      "index": {
        "max_ngram_diff": "3",
        "routing": {
          "allocation": {
            "include": {
              "_tier_preference": "data_content"
            }
          }
        },
        "analysis": {
          "analyzer": {
            "special_char_edge_1_gram_analyzer": {
              "filter": [
                "lowercase"
              ],
              "char_filter": [
                "string_special_character_char_filter"
              ],
              "type": "custom",
              "tokenizer": "edge_1_gram_tokenizer"
            },
           
          "tokenizer": {
            "edge_1_gram_tokenizer": {
              "token_chars": [
                "letter",
                "digit"
              ],
              "min_gram": "1",
              "type": "edge_ngram",
              "max_gram": "100"
            }
        },
        "number_of_shards": "1",
        "number_of_replicas": "1"
      }
    },
    "mappings": {
           
        "name": {
          "properties": {
            "first": {
              "type": "text",
              "fields": {
                "special_char_edge_1_gram_analyzer": {
                  "type": "text",
                  "analyzer": "special_char_edge_1_gram_analyzer"
                }
              }
            }
        }
      }
    },
    "aliases": {}
  }
}
}
}
}
}
}
Query is below,
    
    GET as.contact-154/_search
    {
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "should": {
            "multi_match": {
              "type": "best_fields",
              "query": "christ",
              "fields":     [ "name.first^2", "name.first.special_char_edge_1_gram_analyzer^5" ]
            }
          }
        }
      },
    "_source": ["id","name.first","name.last"],  
      "highlight": {
        "pre_tags": [
          "<span class='text-highlight'>"
        ],
        "post_tags": [
          "</span>"
        ],
        "fields": {
          "name.first": {},
           "id": {}
        }
      },
      "from": 0,
      "size": 100
    }
    
    Result,
    


       {
  "took": 1,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 1,
    "successful": 1,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": {
      "value": 125,
      "relation": "eq"
    },
    "max_score": 62.842735,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "es.contact-154.23-05-12-7-04-12",
        "_id": "127848",
        "_score": 62.842735,
        "_source": {
          "name": {
            "last": "Poeschl",
            "first": "Chris"
          }
        },
        "highlight": {
          "name.first.special_char_edge_1_gram_analyzer": [
            "<span class='text-highlight'>Chris</span>"
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "es.contact-154.23-05-12-7-04-12",
        "_id": "128911",
        "_score": 62.842735,
        "_source": {
          "name": {
            "last": "Rhode",
            "first": "Chris"
          }
        },
        "highlight": {
          "name.first.special_char_edge_1_gram_analyzer": [
            "<span class='text-highlight'>Chris</span>"
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "es.contact-154.23-05-12-7-04-12",
        "_id": "128925",
        "_score": 62.842735,
        "_source": {
          "name": {
            "last": "Hanson",
            "first": "Chris"
          }
        },
        "highlight": {
          "name.first.special_char_edge_1_gram_analyzer": [
            "<span class='text-highlight'>Chris</span>"
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "es.contact-154.23-05-12-7-04-12",
        "_id": "129102",
        "_score": 62.842735,
        "_source": {
          "name": {
            "last": "Cooper",
            "first": "Chris"
          }
        },
        "highlight": {
          "name.first.special_char_edge_1_gram_analyzer": [
            "<span class='text-highlight'>Chris</span>"
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "es.contact-154.23-05-12-7-04-12",
        "_id": "129116",
        "_score": 62.842735,
        "_source": {
          "name": {
            "last": "Sipos",
            "first": "Chris"
          }
        },
        "highlight": {
          "name.first.special_char_edge_1_gram_analyzer": [
            "<span class='text-highlight'>Chris</span>"
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "es.contact-154.23-05-12-7-04-12",
        "_id": "129119",
        "_score": 62.842735,
        "_source": {
          "name": {
            "last": "Sipos",
            "first": "Chris"
          }
        },
        "highlight": {
          "name.first.special_char_edge_1_gram_analyzer": [
            "<span class='text-highlight'>Chris</span>"
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "es.contact-154.23-05-12-7-04-12",
        "_id": "129147",
        "_score": 62.842735,
        "_source": {
          "name": {
            "last": "Dudlery",
            "first": "Chris"
          }
        },
        "highlight": {
          "name.first.special_char_edge_1_gram_analyzer": [
            "<span class='text-highlight'>Chris</span>"
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "es.contact-154.23-05-12-7-04-12",
        "_id": "1264420",
        "_score": 62.842735,
        "_source": {
          "name": {
            "last": "Jaquess",
            "first": "Chris"
          }
        },
        "highlight": {
          "name.first.special_char_edge_1_gram_analyzer": [
            "<span class='text-highlight'>Chris</span>"
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "es.contact-154.23-05-12-7-04-12",
        "_id": "1264421",
        "_score": 62.842735,
        "_source": {
          "name": {
            "last": "Jaquess",
            "first": "Chris"
          }
        },
        "highlight": {
          "name.first.special_char_edge_1_gram_analyzer": [
            "<span class='text-highlight'>Chris</span>"
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "es.contact-154.23-05-12-7-04-12",
        "_id": "127930",
        "_score": 60.612587,
        "_source": {
          "name": {
            "last": "Vanderzanden",
            "first": "Christine"
          }
        },
        "highlight": {
          "name.first.special_char_edge_1_gram_analyzer": [
            "<span class='text-highlight'>Christ</span>ine"
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Latest Result,

```
{
  "took": 1,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 1,
    "successful": 1,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": {
      "value": 125,
      "relation": "eq"
    },
    "max_score": 104.737885,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "es.contact-154.23-05-12-14-34-46",
        "_id": "127848",
        "_score": 104.737885,
        "_source": {
          "name": {
            "last": "Poeschl",
            "first": "Chris"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "es.contact-154.23-05-12-14-34-46",
        "_id": "128911",
        "_score": 104.737885,
        "_source": {
          "name": {
            "last": "Rhode",
            "first": "Chris"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "es.contact-154.23-05-12-14-34-46",
        "_id": "128925",
        "_score": 104.737885,
        "_source": {
          "name": {
            "last": "Hanson",
            "first": "Chris"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "es.contact-154.23-05-12-14-34-46",
        "_id": "129102",
        "_score": 104.737885,
        "_source": {
          "name": {
            "last": "Cooper",
            "first": "Chris"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "es.contact-154.23-05-12-14-34-46",
        "_id": "129116",
        "_score": 104.737885,
        "_source": {
          "name": {
            "last": "Sipos",
            "first": "Chris"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "es.contact-154.23-05-12-14-34-46",
        "_id": "129119",
        "_score": 104.737885,
        "_source": {
          "name": {
            "last": "Sipos",
            "first": "Chris"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "es.contact-154.23-05-12-14-34-46",
        "_id": "129147",
        "_score": 104.737885,
        "_source": {
          "name": {
            "last": "Dudlery",
            "first": "Chris"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "es.contact-154.23-05-12-14-34-46",
        "_id": "1264420",
        "_score": 104.737885,
        "_source": {
          "name": {
            "last": "Jaquess",
            "first": "Chris"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "es.contact-154.23-05-12-14-34-46",
        "_id": "1264421",
        "_score": 104.737885,
        "_source": {
          "name": {
            "last": "Jaquess",
            "first": "Chris"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "es.contact-154.23-05-12-14-34-46",
        "_id": "127930",
        "_score": 102.020966,
        "_source": {
          "name": {
            "last": "Vanderzanden",
            "first": "Christine"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: You're searching for "christ" and the word "chris" is closer to it than "Christine" so it receives a higher score.
You can add to the end of the URL `_explain?pretty=1` and you should see more details about the score

Comment: Can you share the mappings and settings of your index please? I'm fearing that the edge-ngram analyzer is also kicking in at search time, which is not desired.

Comment: "special_char_edge_1_gram_analyzer": {
              "filter": [
                "lowercase"
              ],
              "char_filter": [
                "string_special_character_char_filter"
              ],
              "type": "custom",
              "tokenizer": "edge_1_gram_tokenizer"
            }

Comment: "tokenizer": {
            "edge_1_gram_tokenizer": {
              "token_chars": [
                "letter",
                "digit"
              ],
              "min_gram": "1",
              "type": "edge_ngram",
              "max_gram": "100"
            }
        }

Comment: "mappings": {
           
        "name": {
          "properties": {
            "first": {
              "type": "text",
              "fields": {
                "special_char_edge_1_gram_analyzer": {
                  "type": "text",
                  "analyzer": "special_char_edge_1_gram_analyzer"
                }
              }
            }
        }
      }
    }

Comment: It seems, the edge-ngram analyser is only working. I can see the hits with highlights like,{
        "_index": "es.contact-154.23-05-12-7-04-12",
        "_id": "127848",
        "_score": 62.842735,
        "_source": {
          "name": {
            "last": "Poeschl",
            "first": "Chris"
          }
        },
        "highlight": {
          "name.first.special_char_edge_1_gram_analyzer": [
            "<span class='text-highlight'>Chris</span>"
          ]
        }
      }

Comment: Can you add that in your question instead of comments?

Comment: added analyser and mapping into my question

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the edge-ngram analyzer is also kicking in at search time, and hence, the searched string `christ` is resolved to `chris` by the analyzer at search time and matches the first records. That's not desired.

You should modified your mapping like this and specify a `standard` `search_analyzer` so that the searched text doesn't get edge-ngramed:

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "name": {
      "properties": {
        "first": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "special_char_edge_1_gram_analyzer": {
              "type": "text",
              "analyzer": "special_char_edge_1_gram_analyzer",
              "search_analyzer": "standard"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: if we add standard search analyzer, it was not showing the other documents for " Chris" document. I need those documents also.

Comment: Based on your query, it was not showing the first record for "christ". it is showing "Chris".

Comment: Can you post the result you get with my query so I can compare with your earlier results?

Comment: Modified my question itself. it is the latest result section